# Sending Metadata when Upload is async in Kendo Upload - Metedata is Null

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using async Upload using Kendo. I am passing metadata as below :

```
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/upload/metadata

<body>
<div id="example">
    <div>
        <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <div id="FldUpload" style="width:100%;height:40%;">
                <b>Matter ID : </b><span id="spanMatterName"></span><br />
                <div><input name="files" id="folders" type="file" multiple /></div>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>



$("#folders").kendoUpload({
  async: {
       saveUrl: baseAddrs + "/" + "DragAndDrop/ChunkSave",
       removeUrl: baseAddrs + "/" + "DragAndDrop/remove",
       chunkSize: 10530000, //~ 10MB
       autoUpload: true,
       concurrent: true
     },
         upload: onUpload,
         directory: true,
         directoryDrop: true,
});

function onUpload(e) {
    e.data = {
        EntityID: document.getElementById("spanMatterName").textContent
    };
    alert(e.data.EntityID); // It has correct value
}

//Codebehind
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ChunkSave(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string metaData)
 {
    //Here metadata is always null
 }
```

Why metadata is null ? how does i pass metadata value of (e.data) to codebehind POST method ?

Comment: Per the documentation: `If set, e.formData replaces the payload of the upload request.` Could you setup a debugger or use `console.log` to inspect if `e.formData` is null?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The parameter name should be exactly same what you pass in e.data in my case it is EntityID but i declared variable as string metadata in post method:

```
 e.data = {
        EntityID: document.getElementById("spanMatterName").textContent
    };

It should be 
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ChunkSave(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string EntityID)
 {
    
 }
```